# I want to hide footerview in UItableview

Tags: iphone, ios

I have One segment control. When I clicked on One segment that time I want to show FooterView and when i clicked on second that time I want to hide FooterView.

Comment: Bit more information would be useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"One", @"Two", nil];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(35, 200, 250, 50);
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventChanged];
[self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
[segmentedControl release];

- (void)ButtonPress:(id)sender 
{
    if([sender selectedSegmentIndex] == 0)
    {
        //put your code as per condition
        footerView.hidden = FALSE;
    } else {
        //put your code as per condition
        footerView.hidden = TRUE;
    }
}
```